# Jupyter notebook in PyCharm. Notebook kernel doesnt match project interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

Выводит ошибку "Notebook kernel doesnt match project interpreter и не выполняет ячейки, даже не отображает их в предпросмотре. Причем сервер запускается и в браузере все отлично работает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии "Register project interpreter as kernel" выдает ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интерпретатор проекта и юпитера один и тот же
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем дело?

Comment: После переустановки pycharm и перезагрузки проблема с невыполнением ячеек ушла, но надпись о разнице в интерпретаторах осталась, также не ушла ошибка при регистрации интерпретатора

Comment: Ошибка регистрации это баг вызванный использованием conda https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-41311

Comment: Спасибо. Способ предложенный по ссылке помог.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Способ борьбы изложен по ссылке youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-41311

Необходимо переустановить pyzmq через pip в виртуальном окружении анаконды

```
(recommender) C:\dev\recommender>pip uninstall pyzmq
Found existing installation: pyzmq 18.1.1
Uninstalling pyzmq-18.1.1:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\dmitryb\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\envs\recommender\lib\site-packages\pyzmq-18.1.1-py3.7.egg-info
    c:\users\dmitryb\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\envs\recommender\lib\site-packages\zmq\*
  Would not remove (might be manually added):
    c:\users\dmitryb\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\envs\recommender\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cffi\__pycache__\_cffi_ext.c
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled pyzmq-18.1.1

(recommender) C:\dev\recommender>pip install pyzmq
Collecting pyzmq
  Downloading pyzmq-19.0.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (1.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.1 MB 2.2 MB/s
ERROR: jupyterlab 1.2.6 has requirement jupyterlab_server~=1.0.0, but you'll have jupyterlab-server 1.1.0 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: pyzmq
Successfully installed pyzmq-19.0.0
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/568798)

Comment: Спасибо. Добавлю. Думал о копирайте )